# Ether.li recovery algorithm does not work for me, how to overcome this?

Tags: wallets, ether, recovery, ether.li

Unfortunately, I have used Ether.li to store some Ether. Now I want to recover my Ether Classic (not supported by Ether.li) by setting up the contract manually on the Classic blockchain. That is so far impossible because I cannot derive the needed private key from the printed "Encrypted private key". The problem is that the printout does not distinguish between 'l' (small L) and 'I' (big i).

I have tried all possible variants of the above letters at https://www.ether.li/recovery but always a message pops up "Please ensure that you have properly entered you encrypted private key and/or password".

I see no way to obtain the private key from the printout. (Added: see also my comments below.)

The encrypted key should also be stored somewhere in a browser database. I tried to find it there with the resource tab of the Chrome debugging console but could not find it. Does someone know where to look?

Maybe the developers could add a function to display the (encrypted) private key when I'm logged into the account? That could even be somewhat hidden, e.g. over a non-linked to subfolder like for example `ether.li/private_key`. I would really appreciate that!

Comment: I have just tried to replicate the whole thing with a new Ether.li wallet and found that the printout is such that the printer always cuts off some characters in an overly long line. This is not immediately visible after the printout. Only a comparison with a directly copied version made me aware of this problem. Therefore my only chance is to get the key from the browser. Does someone from Ether.li listen here?

Comment: I might have been experiencing the same problem. Is it possible to help me aswel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your statement, there is nothing wrong with the algorithm behind the wallet. As you have supposed, the encrypted xprv can be found if you use the Chrome debug tools.

We are also happy to assist with recovery of your encrypted xprv. Please email us from the account that the wallet belongs to, and we will ask you challenge questions before revealing it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the account belongs to a friend who asked me for help. He will contact you shortly.

Comment: And yes, there is nothing wrong with your algorithm except that the printout in a second test on a different PC/printer again has cut off the private key and I would not have noticed that if I were not looking for it painstakingly. Because that is a critical issue you might want to improve the output formatting.